# CSS3 background image color transition effect for an image or more

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to do something like a warning effect over a image, and change the image to a red color softly, every some time, but it doesn't work,this only disappear...
Please could somebody help me with this?

HTML:

```
<span id="test" class="ui-icon ui-icon-info state1"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.state1 {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.state2 {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

JS:

```
var f = document.getElementById('test');
f.addEventListener("transitionend", updateTransition, true);

 function updateTransition() {
  var el = document.querySelector("span.state1");

  if (el) {
    el.className = "state2";
  } else {
    el = document.querySelector("span.state2");
    el.className = "state1";
  }

  return el;
}

var intervalID = window.setInterval(updateTransition, 7000);
```

Is convenient do something like this?, or is most reliable do a gif image with this effect?

Thinking that gif image have a poor resolution and also I want put a large list of items like this [20x web page] and I have several SetInterval() functions to update some fields.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/JtpxD/1/

Thanks

Comment: I would say you could save yourself a lot of headache and time if you created a 4 second gif to repeat infinitely. Then instead of having to make sure the script and css follows it around, you can just apply the gif to wherever need be.

Comment: No No. No GIFS. No. CSS Animation - Yes! lol. It depends on your needs. CSS Animations means less loading because there is no image to load, only a few CSS lines. CSS Animation is also a lot smoother (and hardware-accelerated!). But for small images, I don't see how it matters one way or the other.

Comment: CSS Animation or GIF?, I want know that...

Comment: In ui-icons, you have aprox 100 icons. If you are going to use only some, and are not going to scale them up, GIF is ok. If you are going to use maybe 30 icons, and maybe with 2 or 3 different colors, the GIF way will be hard ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the className

```
el.className = "state2";
```

resets the classes, so you lose the `ui-icon ui-icon-info` classes.
you'd want

```
el.className = "ui-icon ui-icon-info state2";
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/ztEk5/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/MxAX9/1/

basically your code

```
el.className = "state2";
```

replaced all class for the span to "state2", i.e. "ui-icon", "ui-icon-info" will be removed